# Javascript file not linking to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to link a javascript file to my header.php so users can login via a popup form. The popup form is there, just hidden, and I'm using javascript to show it when the login button is clicked.

The file won't link though?

I've added a basic alert to check if it is at all linked and nothing happens.

```html
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/assets/js/loginPopup.js'?>"></script>
```

Does that look wrong to anyone? Proper pulling my hair out, cheers for any help

Comment: So what does that translate to when you look at the Page Source

Comment: PHP processes before the page is sent to the browser, javascript afterwards. If something is not loading right, look at the source in the browser to see if it looks correct there first.

Comment: It looks fine to me, '<script src="http://localhost/weinspire/blog/assets/js/loginPopup.js"></script>' that is what shows.

Comment: Open "Developer tools" in your browser and see if you get any errors in the console. You can also open the "network" tab and reload the page to see what files are loaded and what the status is. Don't forget to empty the cache when you've change your js file as well.

Comment: At the risk of getting a virtual slap, from my betters, I would do `<script src="assets/js/loginPopup.js"></script>`

Comment: Getting ERR_ABORTED 404 in the console

Comment: Then the URL seems to be wrong.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I actually prefer to do it like that, but I tend to start with a `/`. :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson as in I'm not linking to the correct file? Or any file rather?

Comment: There's two errors though, one is the 404 error and another says 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at loginPopup.js:12', so surely it's found the file as it knows I'm using event listeners from within it?

Comment: `localhost`, not being a full out domain name, may be being processed as a folder instead of the host. Either the BASE_URL needs to have the `http://` in front, or do as RiggsFolly and Magnus suggested, and drop the BASE_URL and start it with a `/` instead.

Comment: Ah, if you get that error, your file does get loaded. Fix that error and try again.

Comment: @aynber - I think they do get http://, since the URL in the comment became a link. I think it's just them not printing it as `code` that hides it for us. Just a guess though.

Comment: Sorted it guys thanks!

Comment: it seems you forgot add  semicolon -> ";" after echo in php line

Answer (score 1):

Your URI to the script should start with `http://` like

```
<script src="http://localhost/weinspire/blog/assets/js/loginPopup.js"></script>
```

or maybe

```
<script src="http://localhost/assets/js/loginPopup.js"></script>
```

optionally, relative from the root

```
<script src="/assets/js/loginPopup.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, the browser treats this as a relative path to `localhost` subfolder within the root of your virtual host.

TIP1: As some already pointed in comments, you should also use Inspection tools of your browser like Console and Network, to check why your path is not valid.

TIP2: it's always better to use some local domains like `http://myproject.loc` instead of `http://localhost` for many reasons.

Comment: They mentioned in the comments that they get a js-error in the console in that file, so it seems to be loaded. When they copy/pasted the code into the comment, SO hides `http://` when turning it into a link (which it wouldn't have done without the scheme). Here's the difference: as text: http://localhost, as code: `http://localhost`

Comment: SO hides protocol of link when it's placed in the text, but not, when you placing it in a code block, as can be seen in ma answer. like (both added with protocol) http://localhost vs  `http://localhost`

Comment: Yes, and the OP only posted the generated link in a comment as text, not as code, which is why we don't see the URL scheme.  But the URL got turned into a link, which means that it must already have contained the URL scheme. :-)